# $\exists k$ s.t. $k^m\le 1^m+2^m+...+(k-1)^m <2\cdot k^m$?

Tags: nt.number-theory

Can it be shown that,for all $m\in\mathbb{Z}_+$ there exists at least one $k$ with respect to $m$ such that

$$1\le \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}i^m}{k^m}<2$$

*Example*: let $m=1$ then $k=\{3,4\}$

This question has already been asked on MSE but it has not received a solution so that's why I posted here. Given claim solve my first claim from this post ["Observation on Erdős–Moser equation".](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3546797/647719)

[Post on MSC](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3552104/647719)

Comment: Does [Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula) help? At least, it seems to imply that such $k$ exists (and is between $m+1$ and $2(m+1)$) once $m$ is large enough.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. Note that for large $k$ we have $1^m+\dots+(k-1)^m\geqslant k^m$. Choose minimal $k$ with such property. Then $k>2$ and $$2k^m>2(k-1)^m>1^m+\dots+(k-1)^m$$

by minimality.